# How to set a default return value in a Rhino Mocks stub

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Say I want to use Rhino Mocks to generate a stub of the following interface:

```
public interface IFooBar
{
  string Foo(string bar);
}
```

I stub the method `Foo` in the one-time setup method for my suite of unit tests, along with the following constraints:

```
  var foobar = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFooBar>();
  foobar.Stub(f => f.Foo(Arg<string>.Is.Equal("string1")))
    .Repeat.Any()
    .Return("result1");
  foobar.Stub(f => f.Foo(Arg<string>.Is.Equal("string2")))
    .Repeat.Any()
    .Return("result2");
  //etc...
```

Currently, if the parameter `bar` doesn't match any of the constraints above, the method `Foo` will return `null` by default. Is there some way I can tell it to return something other than `null` in these cases (e.g. an empty string or some other arbitrary string)?

I've tried searching the documentation, SO, and elsewhere online but haven't yet found a solution that does what I want.

I tried adding this to the beginning, hoping the subsequent calls to `foobar.Stub` would "override" this default behavior when the more specific constraints were satisfied:

```
  foobar.Stub(f => f.Foo(Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
    .Repeat.Any()
    .Return(string.Empty);
```

Unfortunately that isn't the case; adding the above causes `Foo` to *always* return an empty string, as if none of the other `Foo.Stub` calls ever happened.

I could do the opposite and make the above call *after* all the other `Foo.Stub` calls, effectively covering all the remaining possible cases. The downside to this approach is once I do that, I can no longer add any other constraints that may be specific to one particular unit test but not any others.

Worst case scenario, I can extract all the common `Foo.Stub` calls into a reusable method to call at the beginning of each unit test, followed by more test-specific stubs, and finally the above stub that covers the remaining cases. I'm just wondering if there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a Method Implementation using the input parameters

> Instead of using a `.Return()` with a simple value, you can provide a full implementation of the method using the `.Do()` method. This also allows you to get access to the input parameters.  If you want, you can define a delegate and just call the delegate.

For example

```
//Arrange
var foobar = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFooBar>();
foobar.Stub(_ => _.Foo(Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
  .Repeat.Any()
  .Do((Func<string, string>)(input => {
      if (input == "string1") {
          return "result1";
      } else if (input == "string2") {
          return "result2";
      }
      return string.Empty; // or some other arbitrary string
  }));

//Act & Assert to prove it works (using FluentAssertions)
foobar.Foo("string1").Should().Be("result1");
foobar.Foo("string2").Should().Be("result2");
foobar.Foo(null).Should().Be(string.Empty); // or some other arbitrary string
```

Comment: Thank you! That should provide all the flexibility I need.